# Voltage drop in ESP32 ADC reading when adding devices

Tags: adc, troubleshooting, esp32

I've setup an ESP32 for reading a voltage from its internal ADC as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftQwoh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have the ESP32 ADC configured to sample from `ADC_UNIT_1` on pin `ADC1_CHANNEL_7`.  I am using the attenuation `ADC_ATTEN_DB_0` and width `ADC_WIDTH_BIT_12`.

The [documentation for the `ADC_ATTEN_DB_0` attenuation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html#_CPPv425adc1_config_channel_atten14adc1_channel_t11adc_atten_t) shows that the suggested range of input is from 100mV to 950mV.

I am measuring a pressure sensor that outputs 4.5V at its maximum reading (100psi) and 0.5V at its minimum reading (0psi).

I chose the 5.6kΩ and 1.5kΩ resistors so when the probe outputs 4.5V, the resistor divider output at `VOUT` is 951mV and when the probe outputs 0.5V the resistor divider output is 106mV.

The 100nF capacitor was chosen based on Espressif's [Minimizing Noise](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html#minimizing-noise) documentation, and I am following their [sample code](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/peripherals/adc/main/adc1_example_main.c) and recommendations for multisampling.  Additionally, the ADC is characterized using the factory-set efuse reference voltage.

When configured like this, all is well.  For any range of `VIN` values from 0.5 to 4.5V, I get the expected `VOUT` value and the ADC reads the `VOUT` value very accurately.

The problem comes when I add additional devices to the circuit, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f78Pyn.png)</sup>

Now, when I read the ADC value, I notice a voltage drop, and the drop increases as the peripherals draw current (though not strictly linearly).  For example:

With no peripherals,

`VIN` @ 4.5V shows 952mV at `VOUT` on the multimeter and the ADC reads 953mV (close enough, OK).

With one peripheral drawing 20mA, I now see:

`VIN` @ 4.5V shows 952mV at `VOUT` on the multimeter but the ADC reads 950mV (this is very consistent).

When that same (or another) peripheral increases the current draw to 87mA, I see:

`VIN` @ 4.5V shows 952mV at `VOUT` on the multimeter but the ADC reads 941mV.

Is the voltage drop I'm reading caused by noise?  Or is there some critical thing I've left out of the circuit (I do have bypass caps on the ICs, but I didn't show them in the schematics for simplicity)?

I'm a total electronics noob and this is only the second PCB I've made so I think it's likely I have a ground loop (I was careful not to make one with my traces and used a star ground, but then I did a ground pour so I probably made a ground loop anyway).

If there are any other likely causes I should look at please let me know.  I'm learning all the time, thank you for your time to reply.

**EDIT:**

I've updated the schematic to show how I'm powering things.  I'm using a 7.5V, 1A wall wart that connects to a [ST LD1117 3.3V fixed-output linear regulator](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ld1117.pdf).  I have both required capacitors (datasheet page 8) attached, the 100nF capacitor is a ceramic capacitor, the 10uF is an electrolytic (it's what I had on hand, not sure if it makes a difference).  The regulator is capable of delivering 800mA.

When I measure the `VDD33` pin of the ESP32 (connected directly to the supply) with no peripherals attached, I see 3.315V.

As I attach peripherals (which use the same 3.3 supply as shown in the second schematic), I see the voltage at the `VDD33` pin rise slightly with each component.  The first component causes the supply voltage to rise to about 3.330V, and when I add four components it goes all the way up to 3.370V, so there's a rise of about 55mV when multiple components are connected.

The components I'm adding are [Electrically Isolated Carrier Boards from Atlas Scientific](https://www.atlas-scientific.com/files/Isccb.pdf) and to those various sensors such as their [EZO-pH sensor](https://www.atlas-scientific.com/files/pH_EZO_Datasheet.pdf).

The schematic on page 5 of the electrically isolated carrier board's datasheet is shown below (note that it's an internal schematic -- the only thing exposed to my device are 5 pins, VCC, GND, EN, SDA, and SCL, where VCC is 3.3V from my LD1117 and EN is pulled to VCC through a 10kΩ resistor).

[image: Electrically Isolated Carrier Board Schematic from datasheet]

Comment: Where is the 3V3 supply coming from? Looks like it drops when more current is being drawn as it may not be capable of delivering more current. That's why your ADC measures lower than expected (the lower the ref voltage, the lower the ADC value).

Comment: @RohatKılıç I'm using a 7.5V, 1A power supply which feeds an ST Micro LD 1117 3.3V linear regulator.  The regulator is rated for 800mA and my circuit isn't drawing anywhere close to that.

Comment: The linear regulator does require an output capacitance of at least 10uF, as suggested in the datasheet. You should have placed one if there isn't any. You may want to measure the 3V3 lane when other chips/circuits are connected. It really looks like the regulator's output voltage is dropping.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thank you for your comments!  I updated my question showing how I've connected the power supply.  I am using a .1uF and 10uF capacitor on the regulator input and output respectively as shown in the datasheet.  I measured the 3.3V regulator output and it actually rises as I add peripherals.  With no peripherals the voltage is 3.315V and with four attached it goes up to 3.370V, so a rise of 55mV.  Maybe this is what is affecting the ADC reading, but I would have expected a voltage drop.  I'm not sure why this is happening or how to deal with it.